# main menu: task and backstack on android

Tags: android

I am having trouble to figure out how to implement a main menu correctly. The following thing is going on:

MainMenu -> ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> MainMenu

I want to supress being able to go back to ActivityC (and ActA & ActB likewise) when I am back at the MainMenu. My first clue was to override the back-button and do nasty stuff like killing the App by its PID, but I know that's discouraged, so...

There are many interesting flags for intents, like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, but none of them works. 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP causes to close the App immediately as I reach the main menu (best result so far...), the others had no effect at all, pressing back just returned be back to ActivityC.
I tested them all, not only these four, all activity flags... I also tested to define android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" for the main menu, without success.

Oh yeah, I am dealing with 2.2, API level 8

Any suggestions are highly appreceated. 
Best Regards!

Comment: would you like to use general solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sollution suggested over here is perfect:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678500/1841940

I register a BroadCastListener on all Activities that should be removed from the backstack and when I reach the main menu, I just send the broadcast and all receivers call finish().

This works really great!

Answer (score 0):

Must override method OnKeyDown in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //TODO: killing the App by its PID 
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```